# Crack: Runtime Error 6 Overflow

Tags: vba

I'm trying to format phone numbers such that they start with the correct country codes. For example, if Singapore is found under J2, I would want K2 to reflect 65XXXXXXX (Singapore's country code being +65). Country is in Column J and Numbers are in Column K.

Being a total idiot at VBA I went around the web piecing up a code that would serve my purpose. I'm close! But there is an error when the number already has the correct country code! I want to leave the number as it is if the correct country code is already there.

Can anyone crack it for me?

```
Sub CountryCodes()


Set wS5 = Sheets("Country_Codes")

Dim arr1()
Dim arr2()

arr1 = Array("Singapore", "Austria", "United Kingdom", "Denmark", "Sweden", "Norway", "Poland", "Germany")
arr2 = Array(65, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49)

With wS5
For Each cell In .Range("J2:" & .Range("J2").End(xlDown).Address)
    Found = 0
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr1)
        If cell.Value = arr1(i) Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = arr2(i) & CInt(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value)
            Found = 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If Found = 0 Then
        'Country not found in arr1()
        NF = NF & "," & cell.Value
    End If
Next
End With

If Len(NF) > 1 Then
MsgBox "These countries could not be found :" & Right(NF, Len(NF) - 1)
End If

End Sub
```

I have a secondary issue. Some of my phone numbers have spaces and "+", e.g. +65 XXXX XXXX. I am trying to get it to be purely numbers, no space, no +. Is there any way I can delete those spaces/+?

Thanks so much.
Bills

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first clean the number with a regular expression, and then add the country code if it's missing.
And to overcome the overflow issue, I would store the number as `Decimal` since it can holds 28 digits.
Moreover, it would be simpler to lookup the country code with a Dictionay/Collection rather than with a loop.

Here is an example to format the phone number with the country code :

```vb
Sub CountryCodes()
    Dim re As Object, ws As Worksheet, cell As Range
    Dim country$, countryCode$, number$, NF$

    ' create the country codes dictionary '
    Dim codes As New Collection
    codes.Add 65, "Singapore"
    codes.Add 43, "Austria"
    codes.Add 44, "United Kingdom"
    codes.Add 45, "Denmark"
    codes.Add 46, "Sweden"
    codes.Add 47, "Norway"
    codes.Add 48, "Poland"
    codes.Add 49, "Germany"

    ' create the regular expression to remove the leading "+", "0" and non digit characters '
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    re.Global = True
    re.Pattern = "^[^1-9]|\D"

    Set ws = Sheets("Country_Codes")
    ws.Columns("K").NumberFormat = "0"

    ' iterate each number '
    For Each cell In ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, "K"), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp))
      country = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value
      countryCode = GetCollectionItem(codes, country)
      number = re.Replace(cell.Text, Empty)

      If Len(countryCode) Then
        ' add the country code if not present at the begining '
        If InStr(1, number, countryCode) <> 1 Then number = countryCode & number

        ' write the number back to the sheet as decimal to avoid overflow '
        cell.Value2 = CDec(number)
      Else
        NF = NF & "," & country
      End If
    Next

    If Len(NF) > 1 Then MsgBox "These countries could not be found :" & Mid$(NF, 2)
End Sub


Private Function GetCollectionItem(obj As Collection, key As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    GetCollectionItem = obj(key)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub CountryCodes()
Dim wS5 As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim found As Long, i As Long
Dim NF As String

Set wS5 = Sheets("Country_Codes")

Dim arr1()
Dim arr2()

arr1 = Array("Singapore", "Austria", "United Kingdom", "Denmark", "Sweden", "Norway", "Poland", "Germany")
arr2 = Array(65, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49)

With wS5
    With .Range("J2:J" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues) ' <~~ go down the last row of column "J" (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "J")) and then climb up (.End(xlUp)) to get extend the range to its last non empty cell. finally select only non empty cells (.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues))
        .Offset(, 1).Replace what:="+", Replacement:="", lookAt:=xlPart ' <~~ remove "+" charachters
        .Offset(, 1).Replace what:=" ", Replacement:="", lookAt:=xlPart '<~~ remove spaces
        For Each cell In .Cells
            found = 0
            For i = 0 To UBound(arr1)
                If cell.Value = arr1(i) Then
                    ' use Left() function to check if the first characters in column K already match the relevant countrycode. 
                    If Left(CStr(cell.Offset(, 1).Value), Len(CStr(arr2(i)))) <> CStr(arr2(i)) Then cell.Offset(, 1).Value = CStr(arr2(i)) & CStr(cell.Offset(, 1).Value) '<~~if they don't then add the countrycode a the left of the string
                    found = 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

            If found = 0 Then NF = NF & "," & cell.Value  'Country not found in arr1()
        Next
    End With
End With

If Len(NF) > 1 Then MsgBox "These countries could not be found :" & Right(NF, Len(NF) - 1)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is that you're using CInt not CDbl.

Integers in VBA are 16 bit so have a range of -32768 to 32767

However treating phone numbers as a long isn't a great plan.
Uk numbers have 12 digits if you include the country code (i.e. my mobile is +44 7980 XXX YYY) and so you will get into trouble even CLng which goes upto 2,147,483,647. You probably can get away with using CDbl as this will allow 17 digits of precision (although excel might try to go into scientific notation).

Basically for a phone number you'll need to treat it as a string, as you may have to deal with +65 for a country code indication and possibly things like xt456 for an extension... It also means you won't need to worry about spaces (although the VBA Replace function could help here)